# Installing MSSQL Adapter for Ruby on Rails fails

Tags: sql-server, ruby-on-rails

I run this command:

```
gem install activerecord-sqlserver-adapter --source=http://gems.rubyonrails.org
```

and it fails with

> ERROR: Could not find a valid gem 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter' (>= 0) in any repository

How can I install the Microsoft SQL Server adapter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the source, and it works:

```
gem install activerecord-sqlserver-adapter
```

Cheers!